# `clang -ansi` extensions

Tags: c, gcc, clang, c89

I ran into an issue recently where the following toy example compiles cleanly using `clang -ansi`:

```
int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; 0; );
    return i;
}
```

but `gcc -ansi` gives the following error:

```
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:3:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
a.c:3:5: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
```

Compiling with `clang -ansi -pedantic` shows that a C99 extension is being used.

```
a.c:3:10: warning: variable declaration in for loop is a C99-specific feature [-pedantic,-Wc99-extensions]
    for (int i = 0; 0; );
         ^
1 warning generated.
```

What other extensions does clang allow with the `-ansi` option? How can I disable them?

Comment: I just a few minutes ago ran into a similar issue: clang allows a variable to be defined after executable code in the same block - legal in C99 but should be illegal in ANSI.

Comment: The complete example above is also illegal in C99, since `i` is not defined when it is used in the return statement. Clang and GCC agree on this. Seems this particular use of a C99 extension makes it legal.

Comment: you are right, I had not spotted that in the OPs code (concentrating too much on my own issues).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to disable extensions in `-ansi` mode, then you want these warnings treated as errors: use `-pedantic-errors` instead of `-pedantic`, or `-Werror` (or both). For more fine-grained control over errors, see the [Clang manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html).

Comment: Thanks. Seems like the list of extensions enabled in `-ansi` mode is nonexistent though.